# Update dropdownlist on a Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh, updatepanel, html-select

I have two dropDownLists in a Panel that pops up. When i change one value in the first dropDownList i want to populate the seconde dropDownList with the value chosen in the first dropDownList. Like i have `AutoPostBack = "true"` the page is always refreshing and the PopUp disappears. When in fact i only want to update the panel on the PopUp.

I´m using `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
            PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="199px" Width="400px"
        Style="display: none">
        <table width="100%" style="border: Solid 3px #D55500; width: 100%; height: 100%"
            cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="background-color: #D55500">
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 10%; color: White; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger"
                    align="center">
                    Insert Product
                </td>
            </tr>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="width: 45%">
                            Category:
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList_Change" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Product:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers> 
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
                </Triggers> 
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="popup_modo" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCommand" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="199px" Width="400px"
        Style="display: none">
        <table width="100%" style="border: Solid 3px #D55500; width: 100%; height: 100%"
            cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="background-color: #D55500">
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 10%; color: White; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger"
                    align="center">
                    Insert Product
                </td>
            </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="width: 45%">
                            Category:
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList_Change" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Product:
                        </td>
                        <td>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList></ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers> 
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
                </Triggers> 
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="popup_modo" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCommand" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: The page refreshes and the popup disappears. What was your change?

Comment: Humm... That was a good way to solve this, but the problem is that he is refreshing the whole page instead of only the panel. Can´t seem to figure out why.

Comment: in content template your html start with tr tag so your page getting refresh..tr is always child of table or thead or tbody not of div

Comment: @bruno your page getting refresh on dropdown selected index change event right?

Comment: My Page is getting refresh because of AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: If i put AutoPostBack="false" the event OnSelectedIndexChanged isn´t triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and the key was in the part where I set the *Items* do *Dropdown*. When you set these *Items* it select the first one after page reload (with autopostback).

If this is your problem try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fillDropDown();
    }
}
```